# Как вернуться к вводу числа в консоль, если ввел текст?

Tags: kotlin

Не могу разобраться, как вернуться к набору числа, если ввел не число, а текст.

```
fun main () {
    println ("Введите первое число")
    var n: Int = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте цикл `while` до тех пор, пока в `n` не появится число:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    var n: Int? = null
    while (n == null) {
        println("Введите первое число")
        n = readLine()?.toIntOrNull()
    }
    println("Число: $n")
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо !!!

Answer (score 1):

Может новичкам пригодиться... Я его победил =) Мой рабочий код... По условию задачи необходимо:

1. Ввести число с клавиатуры в консоль.
2. Введите следующие числа, каждое с новой строки. Используйте для этого цикл. Начните итерацию цикла заново, если пользователь ввёл не число. Используйте для этого нуллабельные типы и elvis-operator.
3. Выведите в консоль количество введённых положительных чисел по окончании ввода чисел. Используйте if, чтобы проверить, что число положительное. Посчитайте сумму введённых чисел.

```
fun main () {
    print("Введите количество вводимых в консоль чисел: ")
    val number = inputNumbers()
    println("Желаемое количество чисел для ввода = $number")
    var mainNum = 0
    var sumAllNum = 0
    var sumPosNum = 0
    var sumAllPosNun = 0
    while (mainNum < number){
        println("Введите число: ")
        val numberString = readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: continue
        mainNum++
        sumAllNum += numberString
        if (numberString > 0) {
            sumPosNum++
            if (numberString > 0)
                sumAllPosNun += numberString
        }
    }
    println("Количество вводов чисел = $number ")
    println("Сумма всех чисел = $sumAllNum")
    println("Количество положительных чисел = $sumPosNum")
    println("Сумма положительных чисел = $sumAllPosNun")
    }

fun inputNumbers (): Int {
    return readLine()?.toIntOrNull() ?: inputNumbers()
}
```

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Подправил, спасибо за комментарий.